# Is it possible to do "from module.foo import * as bar" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In javascript I can `import * as bar from 'moduleFoo'`.

Is there an analogous method in Python3?

Comment: Maybe `import module.foo as bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import moduleFoo as bar
```

You may not need the `as bar`, though. Unlike in Javascript, `import moduleFoo` already inserts the `moduleFoo` module object into the current namespace under the name `moduleFoo`, containing all bindings defined in the module.

Comment: Im going to mark this correct as it is. But the issue, that I'm having is that I `from module.foo import *` into file `config.py`. Then in another module I `import config`. I cant access the variables in `module.foo`.

Comment: @AndrewGraham-Yooll: Watch out for circular imports, and make sure you were trying to access those variables as `config.whatever` instead of just plain `whatever`. Also, make sure you actually have a good reason to use `import *`; there are a few good use cases, and it sounds like your situation *might* fall under one of them, but it's usually best avoided.